# append one CSV to another as a dataframe based on certain column names without headers in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a CSV in a data frame with these columns and data

```
ID.   Col1.    Col2.  Col3   Col4
```

I have another CSV with just

```
ID.   Column2.    Column3
```

How can I append 1st CSV with 2nd data under their corresponding headers, without including CSV2 header

My Expected Dataframe

```
ID.             Col1.          Col2.               Col3              Col4
Data.CSV1       Data.CSV1      Data.CSV1           Data.CSV1          Data.CSV1

ID.DataCSV2.                  Column2.DataCSV2.       Column3.DataCSV2
```

Given the column names in CSV to is different

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

```
df1.append(df2)

   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2   2.0
1     2     3   3.0
2     3     4   4.0
0     3     2   NaN
1     4     3   NaN
2     5     4   NaN
```

> **Sample Data**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2':[2,3,4], 'col3':[2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [3,4,5], 'col2':[2,3,4]})
```

Comment: How will it identify the column names?

Comment: it checks the keys which are common in both the `df` objects and does a append on that. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

you'll need to clean your column names then you can do a simple concat.

```
import re

def col_cleaner(cols):
    new_cols = [re.sub('\s+|\.','',x) for x in cols]
    return new_cols


df1.columns = col_cleaner(df1.columns)
df2.columns = col_cleaner(df2.columns)

#output

#['ID', 'Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3', 'Val4']

#['ID', 'Val2', 'Val3']

new_df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0)
new_df.to_csv('your_csv.csv')
```